# Using cofoja annotations in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, design-by-contract

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ.  When attempting to use cofoja code annotations I receive the following errors when building.

```
Error:java: error in contract: package com.google.java.contract.core.agent does not exist
Error:java: error in contract: package com.google.java.contract does not exist
```

My project is targeting Oracle JDK 1.7.  I'm using the version of cofoja that io.konverge released and IntelliJ 14.1.4.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.konverge</groupId>
  <artifactId>cofoja</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I do not receive encounter errors when building the project from the command line with maven.

EDIT:

Here's a sample cofoja project that compiles fine with maven, but that I cannot build in IntelliJ.

https://github.com/konvergeio/cofoja-example

I've attached the IntelliJ DEBUG build log for this project in a `cofoja` project ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/nhatminhle/cofoja/issues/45

EDIT 2:

Updated question to be specific to the `cofoja-example` project.

Comment: How did you import the project?

Comment: @jschlichtholz I imported it as a maven project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to successfully configure IntelliJ.  Hopefully someone finds this useful.

I had to configure Annotation Processors for the current project.  It was enabled by default, but without the appropriate configuration required for `classoutput`, `classpath`, and `sourcepath` settings.  I discovered the `$PROJECT_DIR$` macro to make relative paths to appropriate project directories.  IntelliJ had a pre-configured macro/variable to my local maven repository, so I used that to refer to konvergeio's published version of cofoja.

I took a screenshot of my configuration:

[image: intellij-cofoja-annotation-processor]

IntelliJ's resulting build log:

```
2015-07-12 14:04:11,448 [   1223]  DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling chunk [cofoja-example] with options: "-g -deprecation -encoding UTF-8 -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -Acom.google.java.contract.sourcepath=/home/seglo/source/cofoja-example/src/main/java -Acom.google.java.contract.classpath=/home/seglo/.m2/repository/io/konverge/cofoja/2.0.0/cofoja-2.0.0.jar -Acom.google.java.contract.classoutput=/home/seglo/source/cofoja-example/target/classes -s /home/seglo/source/cofoja-example/target/generated-sources/annotations"
```

I pushed the fork of Nas's `cofoja-example` project to my github.  I included the IntelliJ project settings.

https://github.com/seglo/cofoja-example

My project's `.idea/compiler.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <option name="DEFAULT_COMPILER" value="Javac" />
    <resourceExtensions />
    <wildcardResourcePatterns>
      <entry name="!?*.java" />
      <entry name="!?*.form" />
      <entry name="!?*.class" />
      <entry name="!?*.groovy" />
      <entry name="!?*.scala" />
      <entry name="!?*.flex" />
      <entry name="!?*.kt" />
      <entry name="!?*.clj" />
      <entry name="!?*.aj" />
    </wildcardResourcePatterns>
    <annotationProcessing>
      <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="false">
        <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
      </profile>
      <profile default="false" name="Maven default annotation processors profile" enabled="true">
        <sourceOutputDir name="target/generated-sources/annotations" />
        <sourceTestOutputDir name="target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations" />
        <outputRelativeToContentRoot value="true" />
        <option name="com.google.java.contract.classoutput" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/target/classes" />
        <option name="com.google.java.contract.classpath" value="$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/io/konverge/cofoja/2.0.0/cofoja-2.0.0.jar" />
        <option name="com.google.java.contract.sourcepath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/java" />
        <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
        <module name="cofoja-example" />
      </profile>
    </annotationProcessing>
    <bytecodeTargetLevel>
      <module name="cofoja-example" target="1.7" />
    </bytecodeTargetLevel>
  </component>
</project>
```